# How to handle SSL certificates for https / secure web sockets on dynamically launched Windows EC2 instances?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, websocket, ssl-certificate, windows-server-2012-r2

I need some guidance on how to deal with SSL certificates for https and wss (secure web socket) connections on dynamically launched EC2 instances.

First, the context:
We are currently using Windows instances on Amazon EC2 to run a server / client setup the following components:
- a "server" executable running as a Windows service (developed in C#/.Net)
- a web server (IIS) hosting a single page web app (developed in TypeScript/React)
- data storage to operate on in Amazon S3
- user authentication via Amazon Cognito

Users can connect to the web app and perform actions on data.
The web app connects to the server executable via a web socket on a certain port (say: 5910).
Command requests are sent from the web app to the server over that web socket.
And during execution of these commands, the server sends command responses back to the web app over that web socket.

Until now, we only had a single EC2 instance configured with a host name (say "mycompany.com") and an entry in the DNS settings with our domain name provider, which points to the IP address of the Amazon instance. We can use "https" for the web app and "wss" for the web socket connection, using a dedicated SSL certificate for "mycompany.com".

Recently, we added a way to launch new instances in EC2 from that first instance ("central").
We're using the EC2 userdata + a power shell script to configure the instances when they starts up.
This is all working fine, and we essentially end up with new instances also running a "server" executable and a web server hosting a single page web app. You can navigate to the public IP address of the new instances, and essentially run the web app connected with the server on a new machine (independent from the 1st "central" instance).

Now, the next thing we will do is: when we launch a new instance from the 1st machine, we will NOT navigate to the public ip address of the newly launched instance, but just switch the web socket connection of the already running web app over to the server executable on the new instance. From then on, actions taken in the web app will send/receive command requests/responses to/from the "server" executable running on the new instance. (In principle, we then don't need to run a web server any longer on the new instance, as the web app contents remains served by the 1st "central" machine.)

This is actually already working, if we run the web page as "http" and the websocket as "ws" (of course, this is not secure).
When we try to use "https" and "wss" (secure web sockets), we ran into the following questions around dealing with SSL certificates for dynamically launched EC2 instances:

In order to use SSL, the web server and the web socket binding need an SSL certificate.

As metnioned above, when we only had 1 instance, we bought an SSL certificate for "mycompany.com" and used if for https connections on port 443 in the IIS web server. And we also used the certificate to secure the web socket connection by doing:
    netsh http add sslcert ipport= certhash= appid={}
As we had only 1 instance and an SSL certificate for the hostname of that instance, this was all simple and working (after setting up the firewall to allow for traffic on the web socket port).

Now that we will launch multiple instances and switch the web socket connection from the central machine to the newly launched machines, how do we handle this?

- Do we have to set a hostname for each instance, and add a DNS entry for each instance?
- Do we then create a new SSL certificate for each instance? I assume we should use a wildcard certificate "*.mycompany.com" for this, but we still need a way to tell the machine it is part of that domain, or the certificate won't be seen as valid.
- If we need to make DNS entries for each new machine that is launched, how do we do that dynamically, as the machines are launched? And how fast is it for these DNS entries to become active?
- Or is there a way to just use the IP addresses (public or private) to connect the socket to, but still use a single domain wildcard certificate for all machines?
- As we will be running the web app from the web server on the 1st (central) instance, and connect with another machine, is there anything special we will need to setup to allow that?
- Can we just keep binding the certificate on the new instances to the port used for the web socket connection, as we did before?

I'm sure many of you have already done this, so any advice very welcome!
Thanks!

Koen

PS
I've read a bit about AWS Certificate Manager and Route 53, but that seems rather complex, so I would prefer not to use that, if possible. If we do really need these, then so be it.

Answer (score 0):

The wise thing to do here is to use Route53, Certificate Manager with EC2 Load balancers & Target groups. All your questions will be answered by them.

Actually, Not using the above will make it more complex for you. All these 4 are very simple services and you will be comfortable when you start to practice and use them.

If you know coding well, terraform can be very helpful.

Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback.
Route53 and Certificate Manager had indeed come across my radar. I wasn't sure if learning the details of these services and setting them up would be worthwhile for what we do, but perhaps it is after all.
I had looked into EC2 load balancers, but that seems to be more suited for cloud systems that need to distribute workload over a set of worker machines that are all the same. In our case, we sometimes need a very big (expensive!) machine and other times a "normal" one, depending on the data sets users will be processing at that moment.

Comment: You re-use the certificates in any load balancers any number of times. You can use load balancer as just a pass-through device if you don't want to share the load - target group can run with a single instance as well. You have the option to add and remove the instances from it. You might need to adapt to AWS based services - if you try to make it on your own, it will be difficult to manage and chances of human errors.